# Storing a dictionary in iOS UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift4, nsuserdefaults

Currently I am:

```
// Save
defaults.set(Settings.hostname, forKey: "hostname")
defaults.set(Settings.current_user, forKey: "current_user")
defaults.set(Settings.access_token, forKey: "access_token")

// Load
Settings.hostname = defaults.string(forKey: "hostname")
Settings.current_user = defaults.string(forKey: "current_user")
Settings.access_token = defaults.string(forKey: "access_token")
```

And have `didSet` on each that would call `save`.

But this seems like bad design. So now I'm trying to write one with `enum`, a `struct` with a value a a type, and an array:

```
enum SettingsKeys: Int {
    case hostname = 0
    case current_user
    case access_token
    static let count: Int = {
        var max: Int = 0
        while let _ = SettingsKeys(rawValue: max) { max += 1 }
        return max
    }()
}

struct TypeValue {
    type: // TODO
}

class Settings: Loopable {
    private static var settings = [Any?](repeating: nil, count: SettingsKeys.count);

    //...
```

But this seems awful, and probably un-Swift.

How am I meant to save/load settings that are used across my whole app?

Comment: I did not get your Question. Possibly you can convert the dictionary to string and store in UserDefaults. And when Getting the same value convert back the String to Dictionary when using it. This will work

Comment: Isn't there a better approach? - Involving object serialisation with coredata? [ @TomHarrington removed this; I tagged the question with it]

Answer (score 1):

I would make `SettingsKey` a `String` enum, not `Int`, and then write a class to load and save values using the keys' raw values.

```
class Settings {
    static let standard = Settings()

    enum SettingsKeys: String {
        case hostname
        case current_user
        case access_token
    }

    private func object<T>(forKey: SettingsKey) -> T? {
        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key.rawValue) as? T
    }

    private func set<T>(_ value: T, forKey key: SettingsKey) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: key.rawValue)
    }

    static var hostname: String {
        get { return self.object(forKey: .hostname) }
        set { self.set(newValue, forKey: .hostname) }
    }

    // etc for other values
}
```

Note that you may not change the enum key names between releases without migrating appropriately.

If you have many settings of the same type (e.g., `String`) then it may be best to combine them into a subscript operator:

```
subscript(_ key: StringKeys) -> String {
    get { return self.object(forKey: key) ?? "uh oh" }
    set { self.set(newValue, forKey: key) }
}
```

Comment: The whole point is to skip having to mention `hostname` more than once. Use of generics does overcome my need for `struct TypeValue`; so that's helpful. I was thinking some serialisation approach might work better, but not sure how to flesh that out efficiently (I could use JSON; but that seems anti-Swift-iOS).

Answer (score 1):

I removed the Core Data tag because your question didn't mention anything related to Core Data, and still doesn't.

To save something to user defaults, everything in your data structure must be property list types. That's arrays, dictionaries, strings, dates, numbers, booleans, and binary data blobs (`Data` in Swift). Also, dictionary keys must be strings. You can't write enumerations or structs directly, you would need to convert them to some other form that only required property list types.

One approach would be to put the settings in a struct and then rely on `Codable` to convert the struct to/from `Data`::

```
struct Settings : Codable {
    var hostname:String
    var current_user:String
    var access_token:String
}

let mySettings = Settings(hostname: "hostfoo", current_user: "userfoo", access_token: "accessfoo")

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let mySettingsData = try? encoder.encode(mySettings)

UserDefaults.standard.set(mySettingsData, forKey: "data")
```

Using Core Data makes no sense unless you have multiple settings collections where it would be awkward to read them all into memory at once. The automatic serialization you allude to is probably the Core Data "transformable" attribute type. Transformables can be automatically converted to/from `Data` if the value conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol. But `NSCoding` requires objects, not structs or enums or whatever, and furthermore only works with classes that inherit from `NSObject`.

Comment: In terms of serialisation efficiency, is Core Data better than JSON?

Comment: The comparison makes no sense because Core Data is not a serialization mechanism. I don't know if `Codable` is likely to be faster or slower than `NSCoding`. You're talking about three strings though, so both will be fast. Using Core Data still makes no sense unless your requirements include a lot more data than you're letting on here.